# Как сделать проверку ввода правильного города при вводе

Tags: android, kotlin

у меня есть способ где при вводе названия города я подставляю в api имя города, и все хорошо работает, но если я введу не настоящий город , то соответственно в api ставится ерунда и приложения вылетает. Я бы хотел сделать так чтобы если города не существует , тое сть вывел ошибку, то появился Toast "введите правильное имя города". Заранее спасибо

```
private fun hasCustomLocationChanged(lastWeatherLocation: WeatherLocation): Boolean {
    if (!isUsingDeviceLocation()) {
        val customLocationName = getCustomLocationName()
        return customLocationName != lastWeatherLocation.name
    }
    return false
}

private fun getCustomLocationName(): String? {
    return preferences.getString(CUSTOM_LOCATION, null)
}
```

Comment: Какая ошибка в логах?

Comment: Вы создаете плагин для Android Studio или все-таки Android приложение? Выставляйте правильные метки.

Comment: Так ловите ошибку и выдавайте Toast. Или делайте запрос на список допустимых городов.

Comment: retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 400 
        at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineCallAdapterFactory$BodyCallAdapter$adapt$2.onResponse(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory.kt:104)

Comment: Я делаю приложение